# Is self promoting a product on Stack Overflow allowed?

Tags: support, moderators

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739682/codeigniter-member-based-solution/9739761). Here are [two](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/0405bink78) [links](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NLT02M7Rx6gJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/9739682/codeigniter-member-based-solution%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in) to the original answer. [The post author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108495/ryan-kempt) promotes his product.

Do moderators care about this? All my edits are rejected.

What can I do now?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't edit an discussion into an answer. That said, flagged as spam, since the author does not disclose his affiliation with the product.

Comment: Post author self promote their product only. But my answer inculde the old answers also. Then why you remove my edits? My edits are accepted two days ago. Please check the edit history.

Comment: They shouldn't have been accepted in the first place. You're adding an completely off-topic discussion to the answer.

Comment: I flagged that answer as spam. It should be removed, not edited.

Comment: You are threat me with flag, why flag, everyone needs to read that?

Comment: The whole QA should not be present on SO. The question is basically *"what should I buy?"*. There's no way the answers would stay updated and useful. The question should be deleted, not protected.

Comment: @Alex Cerbrus is answering your questions, and is not threatening you.  Thank you for raising the quoted answer to our concerns, so that we can properly flag them for reviewers. We reviewers cannot read every single answers (much less moderators), and it depends a lot on SO users like you and me to report them.

Comment: Why is this tagged "moderators"? It isn't about the moderators or moderation. I think you meant to use the [meta-tag:self-promotion] tag.

Comment: Hmm, I find it *very* interesting that two other 1-rep users tried to spam their commercial product to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33061998/19679 , had their accounts and posts flagged and deleted, then we started getting anonymous edits: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9811356 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9811123 inserting a link to that same product in the other answer there. Then you created an account and started your edits: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9845166 , all of which just so happened to have that link in them.

Comment: No you are wrong @Brad Larson, One user promote his commercial product, and we stopped it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One is allowed to mention their own product on SO, provided the product is part of an actual solution that's properly explained, and provided the author of the answer discloses his affiliation with the product.

Comment: Current answer is outdated software. But you accept that. My answer is latest and up-to-date softare?

Comment: Don't ___ever___ edit answers to change them like that. If there's new info, post a new answer.

Comment: Answers must use full to others, the outdated must be replaced with new one.

Comment: @Alex: The question is old as hell. If there's new info, post a ___new___ answer. If there's an answer that contains spam, ___flag that answer___

Comment: Rep system dont allow me to post new answer, so it must edit?

Comment: No, you must ___absolutely not___ edit. Get a little more rep so you can answer, instead.

Comment: On my answer, i dont remove the old answer link.

Comment: I list the old one also.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You just don't change an existing answer that much, especially not if that change includes some off-topic discussion. That is simply not how SO works.

Comment: Dont behave like this, list all links(product), the user can choose the best one from answer.

Comment: @Alex, would you _for once_, read what I'm saying? ___Post a -new- answer___. The existing answer is _crap_ and should be _deleted_.

Comment: The new answer incules the old one, with better answer to the author question, why you dont understand this?

Comment: It's not a _new_ answer. You're editing the existing answer.

Comment: Or you can mod the post and provide all the best link to public(i will stop edit).

Comment: ___NO___. Post a ___NEW___ answer, instead of editing ___TRASH___. That is how SO works.

Comment: This is the issue, i dont have rep to post, please post my answer as new answer?

Comment: Get some rep. It's not like it's hard to get 10 rep.

Comment: @Alex, you can't post a new answer anymore because the question is closed. Nobody can post answers there anymore, regardless of reputation points. And the reason it is closed is because it is a tool request - and these attract spam answers. So - it is, in fact, closed for the very reason you're opposed to the answer.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I didn't even realize it's closed.

Comment: It's closed only recently, Cerbrus. Alex' editing probably brought it to people's attention. @Alex, we've been trying to explain this - you're just using the system in the wrong way. We're not saying you're wrong, but you're going _the wrong way about it_.

Comment: I am using system in wrong way, but you are using stackoverflow, rep, answers in wrong way with self promoting answers

Comment: Apparently _"using stackoverflow, rep, answers in wrong way"_ has gotten a few of us a lot of rep. Weird. The system must be broken beyond belief.

Comment: @Alex I'd try to put things is way that suits your vision. The answer you are trying to edit in its _original_ form is _very_ bad. The question to which it is an answer is _very_ bad. And your edit, though potentially constructive, is _against_ the general flow of community. Hence, your concern is valid, but there is a better way to treat that answer than to edit it, which is, delete the answer.

Comment: The question has been downvoted such that it's now on its way to deletion. When that happens it will take the answer with it. Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks Robert and most importantly cerbrus for take care about this

Comment: @Awal Garg: i can't delete it, rep system protects that.

Comment: @Alex: We can, it should be deleted some time soon.

Comment: @Alex You can't, but some people can :) Thanks a ton for bringing it to the attention of the community. They shall take charge henceforth and have it deleted.

Comment: @AwalGarg: For pony!

Comment: Using system in wrong way is not my motto. But situation bring me to do this to show the real answer to the world.

Comment: The question has been deleted. Crisis adverted.

Comment: Thanks @cerbrus, we have talk much on this :)